# Correctly updating IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, updates

I have **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition**. I haven't been updating it for a while, so I received a notification asking me to update it:

[image: Update notification dialogue]

Clicking on *Download* brings me to [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?fromIDE=#section=linux), asking me therefore to download a 408MB `.tar.gz` file. Does it mean that if I want the updates I should install IntelliJ from the beginning again? Can I update it without going through all the installation process again?

Comment: yes install with new version, because major/big changes can't be send through patch. Don't worry you can use your previous version settings in your new version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) for the seamless updates between the major releases, also vote for [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108061).

Comment: Thanks, I just voted the request you linked. **Toolbox** was also easy to install and to use.